# How to disable the Help key and context sensitive help mode in OSX, especially with Qt

Tags: macos, cocoa, qt, keyboard, nsapplication

I have a cross platform Qt application that's running into some trouble in OSX. There's a feature that OSX has that I didn't even know existed - the 'Help' key. My MBP doesn't have one, and neither does my Apple wired keyboard purchased a year ago. It seems that this is mostly something that older Macs have. Apparently it generates the same scan code as the Insert key on PC keyboards.

Anyways, when the Help key is pressed, the cursor over our application (or any application that receives the Help key event) turns into a little question mark. This seems to be part of what's called 'context-sensitive help mode', as documented in the [NSHelpManager's setContextHelpModeActive: method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSHelpManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSHelpManager/setContextHelpModeActive%3a) and in the [NSApplication's activateContextHelpMode: method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/activateContextHelpMode%3a) docs. From the docs:

> In this mode, the cursor becomes a question mark, and help appears for any user interface item the user clicks.
>
> Most applications don’t use this method. Instead, applications enter
>   context-sensitive mode when the user presses the Help key.
>   Applications exit context-sensitive help mode upon the first event
>   after a help window is displayed.

How many Cocoa developers actually know about this? I'm assuming that clicking on something in the application with this question mark cursor should do something like bring up a help message, but I haven't found a single Cocoa application where it actually does anything at all - not even Apple's apps do anything. In fact, it even seems to put a lot of applications into a strange mode where the cursor text selection is enabled.

The problem is that when we change the application cursor programmatically in Qt when we're in this help-question-cursor-mode, bad things happen. Specifically, our application actually crashes. The crash happens deep inside Cocoa in the NSApplication's NSHelpManager. I'd like to find out why we're seeing this crash, but I'm actually more interested in how we can suppress this 'help' mode. There's nothing in Qt or Cocoa that I can see that would stop it, other than perhaps intercepting and squashing an event, which I haven't tried yet.

Does anyone know any more about this?

Comment: This is a Qt bug, and you should report it unless it has been reported already.